# Very low leakage enhancement mode mosfets

Tags: mosfet, leakage-current

I have a 1.8V logic signal that I would like to use to control an enhancement N-channel MOSFET to switch current through a resistor from the drain to a 3V power rail.

It's in a very power sensitive design. All of the enhancement-mode mosfets I looked at seem to specify max "Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current" Idss as 1 μA, which means if I would want the resistor/drain junction to go close to the 3V rail - say within 0.27V - the resistor would need to be a 270KΩ pull-up, and a 10μA on current, all of which are significant currents in a small battery powered application.

Update: I have limited board space, and need about 6 off devices. I have looked at some TI FemtoFET devices (bit of a pain to place as very small) and TPS22860 ultra low leakage load switches which might work.

Any suggestions - should I be using a different type of device?

[image]

Comment: Include the schematic! Yes even if it is not working/wrong/whatever. You mention "enhancement mode" a lot, almost no-one uses the opposite (depletion mode) as they're very rare and usually not needed. My guess is that you're overcomplicating things but to see that I need your **schematic**.

Comment: Usually the 1uA spec is at 25°C Tj, so you need to consider temperature. 2N7000/2 has a maximum leakage of 0.5 or 1mA at maximum temperature!  That said, the typical leakage is much, much lower, in the nA range. Do you feel lucky?

Comment: What MOSFET on resistance are you considering and, what value of resistor are you considering and what's the worst case volt drop across said resistor when the MOSFET is off.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. I am an old physicist, hence the mention of enhancement mode mosfets. The 1uA is worst case across full temp range for the devices. I will add a schematic

Comment: If the current through that pull-up resistor is an issue, use a **levelshifter IC** instead of this circuit. For example: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0101.pdf?ts=1611681615921&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: "I have limited board space", "bit of a pain to place as very small" these are a bit contradictory. How many of these PCB do you intent to make by hand?

Answer (score 1):

The [ADG601/602 analogue switch](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG601_602.pdf) has very low leakage: -

[image]

And the leakage is lower on a lower supply voltage such as 3.3 volts and 0 volts.

It also has a 2.5 Ω on resistance if that helps?

The supply rail is: -

```
Dual ±2.7 V to ±5.5 V or single +2.7 V to +5.5 V supplies
```

So, just regard it as a load switch.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I have a 0 to 1.8V digital input, so cant meet Vinh

Comment: @Giles then the problem has reduced to how can I make my signal greater than 2.4 volts surely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have limited board space, and need about 6 off devices. I have looked at some TI FemtoFET devices (bit of a pain to place as very small) and TPS22860 ultra low leakage load switches which might work.

Comment: You should mention these constraints and endeavours in your question.

Comment: Indeed - apologies Andy. It is my first post; I will try and include more information next time.

Comment: You can still edit your post.

Comment: @Giles if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.